# Fast way of running multiple php commands on one string?

Tags: php

Sorry not too sure on the terminology to ask this questions. But what is the correct quick way of writing this in php? Does the job but seems excessive. Tried looking for this but my terminology returned no results. Thanks for your time.

```
$matrix_code = $_POST['matrix'];
$matrix_code = strip_tags($matrix_code);
$matrix_code = trim($matrix_code);
$matrix_code = trim($matrix_code, "\"'");
$matrix_code = stripslashes($matrix_code);
$matrix_code = htmlspecialchars($matrix_code);
```

Comment: I think how you have done it is correct and readable. I would not sacrifice readability for number of lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$matrix_code = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim(trim(strip_tags($_POST['matrix'])), "\"'")));
```

edit: although this line was the answer to this question, definitely [David Rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63033342/10464991) 's answer has a better structure for more readability and clean code reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that writing the code in just one line is better, as it is more ureadable.

The way to go is to create a function to encapsulate your logic, and use it everywhere you need it. This way you have a clean code that is readable and easy to find out what is it doing, and also you will have a small function call to encapsulate all it's logic when you need it.

```
$matrix_code = cleanText($_POST['matrix']);

function cleanText($text){
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    $text = trim($text);
    $text = trim($text, "\"'");
    $text = stripslashes($text);
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
    return $text;
}
```